# How to render html on ui modal (bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a modal ui (bootstrap for angular), calls by a popupService, i want passing an html code to my popupService.open methode.
The result isn't what i expect, only some values are html formated but my button isn't render...

```
<b>hello</b> <button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="$close(null)">Close</button>
```

It should be  green but i have only the text...

My code :

**popupService.js**

```
appServices.service('popupService', [ '$modal','$sanitize',
    function($modal, $sanitize, $scope) {

        this.open = function(title, message, size, footer){
           $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'view/component/popup.html',
              size: size,
              scope : $scope, 
              transclude : true,
              controller : function($scope){
                $scope.title = title;
                $scope.templatemessage = message;
                $scope.templatefooter = footer;
              }
           });
        }
    }

]);
```

**popup.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$close(null)">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" modal-transclude ng-bind-html="templatemessage">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer" ng-bind-html="templatefooter">
  <div ng-include="view/partial/test.html"></div>
</div>
```

**app.js in my app controller**

```
$scope.$watch('error', function() {
        //check the error value for load the message by code in current language
        console.log('error : '+ $scope.error);
        if($scope.error != null && $scope.error > 0){
            //display error in popup
            $scope.errorMessage = errorService.GetMessageByCode($scope.error);

            popupService.open($scope.Translate.error, $scope.errorMessage, 'sm', '<b>hello</b> <button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="$close(null)">Close</button>')

            $scope.error = null;
        }

    });
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: Is your only problem that a green button is not being rendered? There is no CSS class for btn-green in Bootstrap by default, so what happens if you change "btn-green" to "btn-primary" or "btn-info"?

Comment: btn-green is a custom class i using everywhere in my app, this class is operational